# How to collect values returned from slave to master in parallel programming?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to find a proper way to collect values returned from slaves to the master in parallel programming. I had asked [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050254/how-to-divide-each-pixel-calculation-of-mandelbrot-into-different-nodes) question earlier on how to divide work to calculate pixel of mandelbrot. I got the answer to how to send the work but am still struggling on how to gather the data and plot it as pixel.

node 0: (master)

node 1:(slave)

```
v[0]  = {2,3,4,5,67,86,56,5} // core 0 holds value of 8 threads of this core
v[1]  = {12,21,4,3,54,65,6,5,4} // core 1 holds value of 9 threads of this core
v[2]  = {1,3,4,54,6,5,65,7,4}  //core 2 holds value of 9 threads of this core
```

node 2:(slave)

```
v[0]  = {2,3,4,5,67,86,56,5} // core 0
v[1]  = {12,21,4,3,54,65,6,5,4} // core 1 
v[2]  = {1,3,4,54,6,5,65,7,4}  //core 2
```

node 3:(slave)

```
v[0]  = {2,3,4,5,67,86,56,5} // core 0
v[1]  = {12,21,4,3,54,65,6,5,4} // core 1 
v[2]  = {1,3,4,54,6,5,65,7,4}  //core 2
```

so when master want those value should the slave append the vector and send or is there any other better way to pass values to the master?

Comment: Similar question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284441/gathering-data-from-different-node-using-mpi-and-c

Comment: but i am not using MPI

Comment: I think i got my answer from this(    http://www.omarflorez.info/index.php?id=parallel-mandelbrot-set ) website,although its MPI I can get a hint on how to do it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the C++11 thread library (or Boost.Thread) then what you probably want is a [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).  They can be obtained in one of three ways:

1. By passing a [`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) to a thread and having it set the value.
2. By using a [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task).
3. By calling [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Here's an example using `std::async`:

```
some_return_type my_work_function( some_input_type const & );

some_input_type inputs_to_slave_threads[] = { /* ... */ };

std::future< some_return_type >
  // launch the slaves, letting the OS decide whether to spawn new threads
  slave_0_future = std::async( my_work_function, std::ref( inputs_to_slave_threads[0] ) ),
  slave_1_future = std::async( my_work_function, std::ref( inputs_to_slave_threads[1] ) ),
  // ...
  slave_N_future = std::async( my_work_function, std::ref( inputs_to_slave_threads[N] ) );

some_return_type
  // block until results are ready
  result_of_slave_0 = slave_0_future.get(),
  result_of_slave_1 = slave_1_future.get(),
  // ...
  result_of_slave_N = slave_N_future.get();

process_results_of_slaves( result_of_slave_0, ..., result_of_slave_N );
```